# webkit transform in visual studio

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, webkit, perspective

Visual Studio 2013 is not allowing me to use the "perspective" value within the "webkit-transform" property, I have updated my Visual Studios and it is still not working and giving me an error. Could someone possibly shed some light on this problem please.

Comment: can you please provide a code that you are not allowed to add

Comment: It is bringin an error when perspective is written, explaining: perspective is not a valid value of -webkit-transform.

            Code: "-webkit-transform: perspective ( 600px );"

Answer (score 0):

you must install this 
    https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83

and also if it does not work install this 
    https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210

Comment: I have installed both, still not providing me with the perspective value. :(

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the "Perspective" property on Visual Studio 2013.2 and it runs well, without any problem, I tried specifying all "Vendor properties" for each browser as follows way:

```
.test {
    background-color: red;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    -moz-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 45deg );
    -ms-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 45deg );
    -o-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 45deg );
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 45deg );
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 45deg );
}
```

Also I try it on each specified browser and runs well, however it would be helpful if you specify better the error.

Comment: My Visual Studio is still not providing me with the "Perspective" value.

Comment: Its saying its not a valid value of css3, but I know that it should be.

Comment: But when you run the code, the browser interprets the css properties normally or also gives an error?

Comment: It runs it normally yes I can see the the images, but it is not moving like it should be